# Javascript/Jquery Code will not run in Dreamweaver

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to run the code shown below in dreamweaver. However, I can't figure out why there is an error on line 7. Dreamweaver is not telling whats wrong. Please advise. Error located at " `verso:` ".

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#btn-left').click(function(e) {
       $(".flipbox1").flippy({
            color_target: "red",
            direction: "left",
            duration: "750",
            verso: "<form id="signup" action=" <?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="get">
          <fieldset>
            <legend>Join Our Mailing List</legend>

              <label for="email" id="address-label">Email Address
                <span id="response">
                    <? require_once('inc/store-address.php'); if($_GET['submit']){ echo storeAddress(); } ?>
                  </span>
              </label>
              <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
              <input type="image" src="i/join.jpg" name="submit" value="Join" class="btn" alt="Join" />

              <div id="no-spam">We'll never spam or give this address away</div>
          </fieldset>
        </form>",
         });
    });
});
```

Edits

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#btn-left').click(function(e) {
       $(".flipbox1").flippy({
            color_target: "red",
            direction: "left",
            duration: "750",
            verso: "<form id=\"signup\" action=\"<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>\" method=\"get\">
          <fieldset>
            <legend>Join Our Mailing List</legend>

              <label for=\"email\" id=\"address-label\">Email Address
                <span id=\"response\">
                    <? require_once('inc/store-address.php'); if($_GET['submit']){ echo storeAddress(); } ?>
                  </span>
              </label>
              <input type=\"text\" name=\"email\" id=\"email\" />
              <input type=\"image\" src=\"i/join.jpg\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Join\" class=\"btn\" alt=\"Join\" />

              <div id=\"no-spam\">We'll never spam or give this address away</div>
          </fieldset>
        </form> ",
         });
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried running on Jsfiddle.net . It gives an error unrecoverable syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this line

```
 verso: "<form id="signup" action=" <?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="get">
```

You're using double quotes to surround the entire string value for verso, but the double quote after id= is making javascript think you're closing the string.

You need to either use double quotes on the outside and single quotes inside, or you need to escape the double quotes with backslashes.

Comment: Please check my edit. I really have no idea what I am doing. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1) Since you open with double quotes you need to either use single quotes in your string or change the opening double quote to a single quote;

Change

```
verso: "<form id="signup" action=" <?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="get">
...
</form>",
```

to

```
verso: '<form id="signup" action=" <?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="get">
...
</form>',
```

2) You need to place a `+` at the end of each line with the html string to tell JS to continue looking on the next line for the string.  Even though JS uses `;` to end lines, they are technically not required meaning JS will end lines on line breaks.